# C# download web-content after submit

Tags: c#, forms, web, download, submit

I need to automate the download of a file from this site http://stats.smith.com/reports/Default.aspx?btnGo=View+Report. My problem is once I click on the submit buttom I lose control and a download dialog pops up. Is there a way to download the file using c# and avoid the download dialog? I'm currently using the WebBrowser object in the Forms assembly to navigate through the page.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class

Comment: The problem with that is I don't have a uri to use to download the content.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save a downloaded file to the filesystem from a web browser, there must be user interaction.  A web page does not have permission to muck about in a client's file system.

If you want to display the page in the browser, you can *try* removing the `Content-Disposition=attachment;...` server response header when the file is downloaded.  This will only work if the client has the browser set to display such file types inside the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't specify what you're using to download the file.

If you're asking if you can have a program that runs on a client (either a WinForms app, a console app, or a Windows Service) then you can download a file from a web site using the [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0f69eh.aspx) class and calling the [DownloadFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile.aspx) method.

The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892042/create-http-post-request-and-receive-response-using-c-console-application) (slightly different than you question, so it's not a duplicate) has a link to show how to download a file that requires an HTTP post first.

If you're trying to somehow automate Internet Explorer via a javascript from a web page you're hosting to force a file to download on a user without displaying the dialog box, then no.  You can't.