# Can I use C# Http class to form Http request for my Application?

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-phone

I am creating a Windows phone application which communicate with other mobiles using sockets.
To send data over sockets, I am using Http Protocol.
Right now I am creating http requests manually(appending strings). 
Can I use C# class to form Http request and send the data over my sockets?

And also can I use C# class to parse the http data which i get over socket from other mobile.

Answer (score 3):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace WebserverInteractionClassLibrary
{
    public class RequestManager
    {
        public string LastResponse { protected set; get; }

        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();

        internal string GetCookieValue(Uri SiteUri,string name)
        {
            Cookie cookie = cookies.GetCookies(SiteUri)[name];
            return (cookie == null) ? null : cookie.Value;
        }

        public string GetResponseContent(HttpWebResponse response)
        {
            if (response == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("response");
            }
            Stream dataStream = null;
            StreamReader reader = null;
            string responseFromServer = null;

            try
            {
                // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
                dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
                reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                // Read the content.
                responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                // Cleanup the streams and the response.
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {                
                if (reader != null)
                {
                    reader.Close();
                }
                if (dataStream != null)
                {
                    dataStream.Close();
                }
                response.Close();
            }
            LastResponse = responseFromServer;
            return responseFromServer;
        }

        public HttpWebResponse SendPOSTRequest(string uri, string content, string login, string password, bool allowAutoRedirect)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = GeneratePOSTRequest(uri, content, login, password, allowAutoRedirect);
            return GetResponse(request);
        }

        public HttpWebResponse SendGETRequest(string uri, string login, string password, bool allowAutoRedirect)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = GenerateGETRequest(uri, login, password, allowAutoRedirect);
            return GetResponse(request);
        }

        public HttpWebResponse SendRequest(string uri, string content, string method, string login, string password, bool allowAutoRedirect)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = GenerateRequest(uri, content, method, login, password, allowAutoRedirect);
            return GetResponse(request);
        }

        public HttpWebRequest GenerateGETRequest(string uri, string login, string password, bool allowAutoRedirect)
        {
            return GenerateRequest(uri, null, "GET", null, null, allowAutoRedirect);
        }

        public HttpWebRequest GeneratePOSTRequest(string uri, string content, string login, string password, bool allowAutoRedirect)
        {
            return GenerateRequest(uri, content, "POST", null, null, allowAutoRedirect);
        }

        internal HttpWebRequest GenerateRequest(string uri, string content, string method, string login, string password, bool allowAutoRedirect)
        {
            if (uri == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("uri");
            }
            // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
            // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
            request.Method = method;
            // Set cookie container to maintain cookies
            request.CookieContainer = cookies;
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            // If login is empty use defaul credentials
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(login))
            {
                request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            }
            else
            {
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(login, password);
            }
            if (method == "POST")
            {
                // Convert POST data to a byte array.
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
                // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
                request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                // Get the request stream.
                Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                // Write the data to the request stream.
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                // Close the Stream object.
                dataStream.Close();
            }
            return request;
        }

        internal HttpWebResponse GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request)
        {
            if (request == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("request");
            }
            HttpWebResponse response = null;
            try
            {
                response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();                
                cookies.Add(response.Cookies);                
                // Print the properties of each cookie.
                Console.WriteLine("\nCookies: ");
                foreach (Cookie cook in cookies.GetCookies(request.RequestUri))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Domain: {0}, String: {1}", cook.Domain, cook.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Web exception occurred. Status code: {0}", ex.Status);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            return response;
        }

    }
}
```

Here is a nice code snippet that you can use as example from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892042/create-http-post-request-and-receive-response-using-c-sharp-console-application).

Comment: I still have doubt... I give byte array to sockets to send. Where will i get the byte array of request you are creating.??

Comment: For the request or the response?!

Comment: For request and response both.

Comment: For request you have: "String content" -> "byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);"... for response just look at GetResponseContent(). YOu normally pass and get data in string format.

Comment: These classes directly try to connect to the webserver specified in the URI via port 80 over internet. But in my case, I just want the request string, convert it into byte array and give it to my sendData() function which opens a socket, connect to the other device over lan, and send the request. Is there a way by which can convert the request created into string or byte array so that i can use it.

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest/quickest way is with [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx). If you need more control you can also use [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx).