# how do I get the value of a different class

Tags: c#

I have two class. how do I get the value of a different class. 
for example ...

```
public class bat
{
    public int a; 

    void valueA()
    {
        int a = 20; 
    }
} 

class nah
{
   public int b;

   void valueB()
   {
       b = a; // variable a from class bat. 
   }   
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the concepts of [inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx) and [composition](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0b6677dc-3eb6-4eae-9c8f-c042ccbfefb3/what-is-composition-in-c-?forum=csharplanguage)? If so: what are your motives for not using either of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an instance of `bat` into `nah`, then reference `a`:

```
public class bat
{
    public int a; 

    void valueA()
    {
        int a = 20; 
    }
} 

class nah
{
   public int b;

   void valueB(bat someBat)
   {
       b = someBat.a;
   }   
}
```

Or make `a` a static variable, so that you don't need an instance of `bat` to reference it:

```
public class bat
{
    public static int a; 

    void valueA()
    {
        int a = 20; 
    }
} 

class nah
{
   public int b;

   void valueB(bat someBat)
   {
       b = someBat.a;
   }   
}
```

---

*Regarding that* `void valueA()` *method in `bat`...*

In the first case, calling `bat.valueA()` is not possible from outside the class because it's not `public`. Also you're assigning `20` to a local variable that goes out of scope when `valueA()` ends.

In the second case, you couldn't call `valueA()` without making it public and static... and you'd still be assigning to a local variable, not the class-level variable.

Answer (score 0):

A class is only a template for the creation of objects. You must create instances of these classes i.e. you must create objects with the `new` keyword.

```
class nah
{
   public int b;

   void valueB()
   {
       bat batObject = new bat();
       batObject.valueA(); // Set the value.
       b = batObject.a; // variable a from class bat. 
   }   
}
```

In .NET programming it is usual to use PascalCase for class names, method names and property names. Many programmers use the prefix "_" for field names. Field names and variable names are written in camelCase. Fields are usually kept private. Use properties for publicly accessible values.

```
public class Bat
{
    public int A { get; set; }

    public void SetValueA()
    {
        A = 20;
    }
} 

public class Nah
{
   public int B { get; set; }

   public void SetValueB()
   {
       Bat bat = new Bat();
       bat.SetValueA();
       B = bat.A;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
public class bat
{
public int a; 

void valueA()
{
    int a = 20; 
}
} 

class nah
{
public int b;

void valueB(bat bt)
{
   b = bt.a; // variable a from class bat. 
}   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can have the `nah` inherit `bat`.

Example:

```
public class bat{
    public int a; 
    void valueA(){
    a = 20; }
} 
------ 
class nah : bat {
   public int b;
   void valueB(){
   b = a; // variable a from class bat. 
   }   
}
```

Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx)

This implies that these classes are both in the same application. If they are not, then you can also accept a type of `bat` as a parameter to `valueB`

```
void valueB(bat Bat)
{
    b = Bat.a;
}
```

Or pass values by HTTP requests, read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892042/create-http-post-request-and-receive-response-using-c-sharp-console-application).

Comment: You can also use composition, turn `bat` into a singleton or use an http request to call an API that returns the value of `a`. The question as posed is too broad to answer and if you're going to answer you should at the very least provide the reasonable alternatives and how they correlate to eachother.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel True.... Check edits...