# how to search web for a keyword typed at runtime?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

Is there any way to search web or some particular sites for a keyword typed at runtime in asp.net. e.g. if i want to search for a particular laptop model on 4,5 websites. What can be done in this scenario? I just need a direction.

Comment: you use c#, vb? i cant understand your problem

Comment: Search the web for "C# make http request" or the likes, find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892042/create-http-post-request-and-receive-response-using-c-sharp-console-application and so on.

Comment: But thats not relevant. In my case i need some searching mechanism so that i can further proceed(If those keywords are found in those web sites) and scrape data from that site.

Comment: Then search the web for "c# parse HTML" and find HtmlAgilityPack.