# Get response from aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, request, response

I want to achieve the most simple thing. That is request a aspx page from a c# console application, and then the aspx page should give a string back to the c# app.

I have searched around alot, but couldn't really find anything :(

Lets say my page is called www.example.com/default.aspx. And from my C# app, i make a request to that page, and then that page should just return a string saying "Hello".

Below, i have wrote in pseudo code on how i believe it should be done.

**C# app**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //1. Make request to the page: www.example.com/default.aspx
    //2. Get the string from that page.
    //3. Write out the string. (Should be "Hello")
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**.aspx code**

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string text = "Hello";
        //1. Return the "text" variable to the client that requested this page
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look here, it is an answer to a similar question but applies here as well
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892042/create-http-post-request-and-receive-response-using-c-sharp-console-application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use System.Net.WebClient class

```
var html = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://www.example.com/default.aspx"));
Console.Write(html);
```

the web page should output the text as

```
Response.Write(text);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer, i got the string back, but i also got the whole html source code. How can i only get the string?

Comment: The page (.aspx file) should be empty (only leave first line with <%@ Page ... in it). If you add any html content in there then you will receive it as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string text = "Hello";
        //1. Return the "text" variable to the client that requested this page

              Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

              Response.BufferOutput = false;
              Response.BinaryWrite(GetBytes(text));

              Response.Flush();
              Response.Close();
              Response.End();
    }

static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return bytes;
}
```

**From Console**

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("http://www.contoso.com/yourPage.aspx");

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
            Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);

            reader.Close ();
            dataStream.Close ();
            response.Close ();
```

Comment: Ok, but what code should i write in my c# application?